# Rails: Passenger not serving multiple requests at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have read that passenger is a multi-process server which means that it can handle multiple requests at a time.

I am running passenger in a standalone mode on my local machine and have written code to check if passenger is able to run multiple requests simultaneously or not. My code is:

```
class Test < ApplicationController

 def index
   sleep 10
 end 
end
```

I am hitting two http requests simultaneously and expecting two requests to return output after 10 seconds but one request returns output after 10 seconds and another one returns output after 20 seconds. So it proves that it is handling one request at a time and not simultaneously.

Does it means that passenger is a single process server and not multi-process server? or I am missing something.

Comment: you can study [nginx + passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/optimization/).. I think it assumes 1 process by default you need to configure it for multi processing

Answer (score 1):

Passenger (along with most other application servers) runs no more than one request per thread. Typically there is also only one thread per process. From the Phusion Passenger docs:

> Phusion Passenger supports two concurrency models:
>
> process: single-threaded, multi-processed I/O concurrency. Each application process only has a single thread and can only handle 1 request at a time. This is the concurrency model that Ruby applications traditionally used. It has excellent compatibility (can work with applications that are not designed to be thread-safe) but is unsuitable workloads in which the application has to wait for a lot of external I/O (e.g. HTTP API calls), and uses more memory because each process has a large memory overhead.
>
> thread: multi-threaded, multi-processed I/O concurrency. Each application process has multiple threads (customizable via PassengerThreadCount). This model provides much better I/O concurrency and uses less memory because threads share memory with each other within the same process. However, using this model may cause compatibility problems if the application is not designed to be thread-safe.

(Emphasis my own)

Comment: well what about clustering here? A passenger can server multiple request with clustering.

Answer (score 1):

try like

```
 def index
    n = params[:n].to_i
    sleep n
    render :text => "I should have taken #{n} seconds!"
  end
```